# "PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key" error on modprobe module.ko

Tags: ubuntu

On Ubuntu 18.04.3, I want to sign a driver which I've built on the same Ubuntu machine and load it via modprobe. This machine has SecureBoot enabled.

After building the driver to get the .ko file, I've attempted to sign the module as follows:

1. I've created a key by running:

```
sudo update-secureboot-policy --new-key
```

like the "**How can I do non-automated signing of drivers?**" section [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) says to do.
(No output/error message)

2. I've tried to enroll the key by running:

```
sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key**
```

as suggested by the same [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot).
(This results in a one-line output I wasn't sure what to make of:
"No DKMS modules installed.")

3. Then I tried signing the modules with the keys by running:

```
sudo kmodsign sha512 /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der my_module.ko
```

as it says to do [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/Signing). (No output/error message)

But when I try installing the module via modprobe:

```
sudo modprobe my_module.ko**
```

I get the error:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'gve': Operation not permitted

The dmesg entry I think is relevant says:

> PKCS#7 signature not sugned with a trusted key

I'm not sure whether this means I have not enrolled the keys I created correctly or what other problems there might be.

This is the output I get from running the following commands:

```
$ mokutil --test-key /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOLK.der
```

And the output is:
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOLK.der is not enrolled

```
$ sudo mokutil --import /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOLK.der
```

And the output is:
SKIP: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOLK.der is already in the enrollment request

Okay, I think my post might be duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur) S/O post, but I'm actually looking to write a script that'll download, build, sign and install the driver but it seems like rebooting is a necessary part of enrolling keys which is a necessary part of signing the driver. Is there a way around this that'll let me automate all of this in a script?

Answer (score 0):

here is some solution.

```sh
sudo -i 
mkdir /root/module-signing
cd /root/module-signing
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=YOUR_NAME"
chmod 600 MOK.priv 
mokutil --import /root/module-signing/MOK.der 
input password: 
input password again:
reboot
```

Enroll MOK,then continue,and then selected yes to enroll the key,and then re-enter the password. Then selected OK.